# How to dynamically access JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a React Child component that looks like this:

```
const SingleProject =(props)=>{
    let data = projectData.VARIABLE_FROM_PROPS.projectDetails;
    let asideData = projectData.VARIABLE_FROM_PROPS.projectSideBar;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props);
    }, []);
    return (<></>);
```

How can I use the value in props: `props.pathname` to get the `projectDetails` data.

Basically, if `props.pathname` is `golly` then I need to be able to get the `data` from `projectData.golly.projectDetails`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do `projectData[VARIABLE_FROM_PROPS]["projectDetails"]`

or

`projectData[VARIABLE_FROM_PROPS].projectDetails`

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed

Comment: This is an **often-repeated duplicate**. Please don't post answers to obviously duplicate questions. Instead, vote to close as a duplicate of the canonical original. The purpose of SO's model is to avoid having hundreds of questions with near-identical answers, making it hard to find and curate good information, in favor of having one set (ideally) of well-curated answers we point all the questions at.